# How to remove trend line from Highcharts Line Chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a `Highcharts` line chart and I need to remove the trend line that constantly appears. Is this a setting that I can disable?

[image]

Comment: can you post the code you're using to create the chart?

Comment: Have you checked browser console for JS errors? Looks like this might be a data sorting issue. Please post a live example or data used.

Comment: As Kacper says - this looks like you are using time-based data but not sorting your data set in ascending time order. It is not a trend line.

Answer (score -2):

An example of the code you're using would help.

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rekrokdz/1/) has an example of a chart with no trendline.

Html

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            min: -0.5,
            max: 5.5
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Scatter plot'
        },
        series: [ {
            type: 'scatter',
            name: 'Observations',
            data: [1, 1.5, 2.8, 3.5, 3.9, 4.2],
            marker: {
                radius: 4
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11498849)